# How to specify a library project in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am using google play services library in my android project. I am not including it as a jar but as a library project in the properties of my project. Now I am getting an error

Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

To solve this a stackoverflow result to include the library in proguard.

I have included library jar files in proguard by specifying the path of the jar file.

How do I include a library project in proguard.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

follow the tutorial here to get idea about how to use libraries and exception rules for progouard

http://www.intellicode.in/using-proguard-for-android-project/

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "include a library project" in ProGuard. You have to add specific rules. The rules for Google Play Services are [shown here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard)

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

These go in your `proguard-project.txt` file in your project root.

Comment: my problem is that my app exceeded 65536 methods and goole play services library alone has 30k methods or so. The reason I am using google play services library is to implement google maps in my app. I want proguard to strip all unused methods from this library. The above mentioned code is to prevent proguard from stripping right?